# How do I allow only certain IPs to access a certain port?

Tags: iptables

I have a central server with a database installed and multiple distributed servers that call that central database.  For security reasons I would like the central server only to be accessed by those known servers.

So what I'm trying to achieve here is to allow port 5432 to be accessed by server 192.168.1.5 and 192.168.2.6.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.5,192.168.2.6 -d ??.??.??.?? -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

Is this correct?

What I don't understand is the option to specify a destination. The destination on INPUT is always the server itself, no? Why is it then configureable?  Do I have to define it or by leaving it out, it will automatically point to the same server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to divide your rule into two rules (I tried it using one command specifying both IPs and it seems to work). The end result is two rules like the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.5 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.6 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

Second, you can leave out the `-d` to just match any IP. Since, this is `INPUT` chain, it requires to match one of the machine IPs.

Third, don't forget to have a `DROP` rule because if you have only these two rules with `ACCEPT` as default policy for `INPUT` chain. All connections will be allowed.

Also, you may need to allow `RELATED`, `ESTABLISHED` traffic for the packets to flow in both directions. This depends on your rules (what is allowed and what is dropped). Here is the rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks Khaled. `iptables -P INPUT DROP` should suffice at the end. Correct?

Comment: @Houman: but you need also to allowed `RELATED`, `ESTABLISHED` traffic as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have a follow up question related to this using custom chains, if you don't mind. https://serverfault.com/questions/1045116/do-i-have-to-return-at-the-end-of-a-custom-chain