# Do I have to RETURN at the end of a custom chain?

Tags: iptables

I have a whitelist for three ports on my server that I would like restrict access to. Only the given three Ip addresses should be allowed to access these ports.

```
iptables -N whitelist
iptables -A whitelist -m tcp -p tcp --dport ${ES_PORT} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A whitelist -m tcp -p tcp --dport ${REDIS_PORT} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A whitelist -m tcp -p tcp --dport ${DB_PORT} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A whitelist -j RETURN

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.101 -j whitelist
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.102 -j whitelist
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.103 -j whitelist
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ${SSH_PORT} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Is `iptables -A whitelist -j RETURN` needed at all?

Please be mindful that the SSH port after the whitelist should be globally set. Hence the chain can't drop unless everything is finished.

Comment: There is an implicit return enacted at the end of user-defined chains, but I cannot find where this is explicitly documented (it *is* mentioned in `-j TRACE` docs). Still explicit is often better than implicit.

Comment: Thank you, so you recommend keeping it there.